# jquery data attr auto system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem.

In my html I have this tags: `data-slider-width="800" data-slider-nav="true"` .

I want to build an automatic system. This is how it looks like

```
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    var data_options_control = function(scope){
        owl = scope;
        console.log(owl.$element.data())
        owl.options = $.extend({}, owl.$element.data(), owl.options);
        console.log(owl.options)
    }
    $.fn.owlCarousel.Constructor.Plugins.data_options_control = data_options_control;
})( window.Zepto || window.jQuery, window,  document );
```

The issue is the function shut find all data attr the i on the html element ex. width and nav and extend in the options ob there alrady exit

Right now it just add 2 now keys to the ob, `sliderWidth` and `sliderNav`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the keys to be called "width" and "nav" instead of "sliderHeight" "sliderNav". To do that, you'll need to rename the keys yourself; what you're seeing is jQuery's naming (you could also change the data- attributes to just "data-width" and "data-nav", but I think that the way you have is probably better, as it "namespaces" the data attributes). Something like [this](http://jsbin.com/yiqez/1/edit).